# ExecuteProcess processor vs NIFI Custom Processor to run a java application jar. Which one is better?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi and am trying to run a java application in Nifi, which one is a better approach

1. Building a java Jar and executing it using ExecuteProcess processor or
2. Building a custom processor

Approach I tried:
The first processor in my Nifi flow is ExecuteProcess.
The java jar I built produces a collection of elements, prints the collection and then the ExecuteProcess processor writes that collection entries as an output Flow file, making it available to the next processor. This is working as expected. But,

1. Is using ExecuteProcess processor the correct way to approach?
2. Are they any drawbacks of using ExecuteProcess processor?
3. Would building a custom processor be beneficial?

Explain me the pros and cons of using a ExecuteProcess processor and a Nifi custom processor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a third option: create a fat jar and attach it to the "module" configuration of the `ExecuteScript` processor. That will add it to the NAR classpath so all of its classes will be accessible to your scripts.